# Parse JSON data in T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I am attempting to parse JSON data from a column in SQL Server.

Here is how the JSON is organized within the column.

```
{
"Organization": [], 
"Purpose": [], 
"CountTotal": INT, 
"Date": DateTime, 
"User": '', 
"Sets": [
  { "Name": 'Set1', 
    "Type": [], 
    "YearRange": {"Min": 2000, "Max": 2010}, 
    "Source": INT, 
    "Details": [
         {
         ZipCodes: [], 
         Include: Bool, 
         Description: ""
         } 
     ]
  }, 
  { "Name": 'Set2', 
    "Type": [], 
    "YearRange": {"Min": 2000, "Max": 2010}, 
    "Source": INT, 
    "Details": [
         {
         ZipCodes: [], 
         Include: Bool, 
         Description: ""
         } 
     ]
  }
]
```

The part I'm struggling with is getting information from the sets into their own column.

I want to be able to select specific parts of the JSON and have each in their own column. Something like this in terms of the column headers:

```
| Org | Set1_Name | Set1_ZipCodes | Set2_Name | Set2_ZipCodes |
```

I have this as the query so far. The part I'm struggling with is getting each part of the individual sets (Name, Type, YearRange, etc) into their own column.

```
select
    json_query(query, '$.Organization') as 'Organization', 
    json_query(query, '$.Purpose') as 'Purpose', 
    json_query(query, '$.CountTotal') AS 'CountTotal', 
    json_query(query, '$.Date') AS 'Date', 
    json_query(query, '$.User') AS 'User', 
    json_query(query, '$.Sets') AS 'Sets', 
    json_query(query, '$.Sets[0]') AS 'Set_1', 
    json_query(query, '$.Sets[0].Name') AS 'Set_1_Name',
from 
    table
```

The above query is giving me what I want for the Organization, Purpose, etc. It's the Sets that I am struggling with. The column I have alias as Set_1_Name is returning NULL instead of the value.

Does anyone know how to parse this out when you have an array of objects within an object?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: That's not even valid JSON: all strings need `""`. Anyway, you need `JSON_VALUE` for scalar values, `JSON_QUERY` is only for objects or arrays